# Need to fire the mountain crossbow but I have no ammunition?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

I've finished Lord of the Rings War in the North, but now when I am playing it again with the same character I'm stuck in the level where I need to fire the mountain crossbows. In my first playthrough it worked without complaint, but now I can't fire a crossbow. I press "E" to use it but it won't fire an arrow. Do I have to find ammunition for it? Why did it work in my first playthrough, but not now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is intentional, the game gets difficult every time you finish it, i played in in Heroic level it was working fine, but in the legendary level the mountain crossbow is not firing.

this is intentional to make the game this time more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I still figured it out!

You have to go to your **Settings**, **Keybindings** and check for the "**Ranged Attack**" it has to be the Left Mouse Button, so as "Attack" is, too.
Then it still works fine! Yeah! :)